# Outlook 2010 Rule for Internal Addresses

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I create a rule that applies to internal email addresses?  Looking for "@company.com" or "company.com" in the sender's address does not work.

Comment: So "with specific words in the sender's address" doesn't work? You could try using "sender is in the specific Address book" if your exchange address book is accurate.

Comment: I'm surprised that using a send rule doesn't work. It is possible that there are restrictions on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Move all messages to the specified folder except those containing "@" in the sender address.